# Is there a graphical front end to the Solaris Service Management Facility?

Tags: solaris, smf

I have a few service errors at startup on an opensolaris installation that I keep put off fixing since I would need to figure out the line commands again. Is there an easier to use front end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenSolaris package repository includes an administration GUI called [Visual Panels](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+vpanels/) you can install by running `pkg install OSOLvpanels` and then it will appear under the System->Administration menu in GNOME as "Services" or you can start it with the command `vp svcs`.

Comment: It looks like it is useful for checking status, stopping and starting. It would be nice if it could be used to add service and adjust them as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Go for `manifold`, it helps you configure the manifest and writes manifest xml file on behalf of you. http://chrismiles.livejournal.com/26279.html

Also, cheatsheet is at http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=182

Zenity, a nice GUI tool for managing the services from graphical console. http://blogs.oracle.com/darren/entry/i_recently_saw_a_libcurses